# Getting wrong CGRect for boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring

I have a UILabel inside UITableViewCell. Height of UILabel depends on the height of UITableViewCell  using auto-layout constraints. Width of UILabel is `176.0` and fixed.

I am using `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` for text inside UILabel to determine the height for the UITableViewCell.

Here are the screenshots showing UILabel configuration in interface-builder

[image]

[image]

This is the code to get boundingRect for the UILabel text.

```
        NSString *text = @"Extra long goods charge";
        CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(176.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]}
                                         context:nil];
```

Size returned is `152.132813, 18.1796875`, but this rect is not large enough to contain `Extra long goods charge` text. Infact, even rect of size `176, 18` cannot contain this text.

My guess is that I am somehow messing with the use of `boundingRectWithSize`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing. Line breaks as "Character wrap" and adding a constraints as the label height.
See if the bounding rect with size returns the correct Value.

If it doesnt, then Remove all the constraints and check for label height and calculate what the row height should be according to all the label height (the value returned from boundingrectwithSize), and adjust the height of the cell in the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableView.  This might be another reason why your text is not showing despite the height of label is showing what it is expected to be.

Try it out once.

[EDIT]

I am not properly getting that you are getting the appropriate height that you should get and that's why its messing with the display of the text.
If that is the case then you can try this method.

```
NSString *message =@"Your text here!";
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
```

Although if this is the case then this above method is deprecated in iOS 7 but it works just about fine.

Comment: 1. How will changing anything in interface builder will impact size returned by boundingRectWithSize:  

2. Problem is size returned by boundingrectwithSize is too small. I tried using this size as frame size for UILabel in interface builder and I can't fit in the text.

Comment: "cannot contain the text" as in "..." comes -incomplete text?

Comment: Core issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562838/weird-behaviour-of-boundingrectwithsizeoptionsattributescontext