# Weird behaviour of boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring

I am experiencing a strange issue related to `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`

This is the code

```
        NSString *text = @"These long strings work";
        CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(176.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]} context:nil];
        CGSize size = rect.size;
```

I have an xcode iOS project which uses this code. When I run the project, the `size` is `(width=149.8125, height=18.1796875)`

I created a new single page application project in xcode and tested the same code there. 
`size` is `(width=172.944031, height=19.0880013)` (which matches the frame size of UILabel created with same title and same font in interface builder)

Apple docs for `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context`:

`Calculates and returns the bounding rect for the receiver drawn using the given options and display characteristics`

Is this behaviour due to some `display characteristics` that might be different across projects?

Comment: So the question is why does boundingRectWithSize: behave differently in 2 separate projects?

Comment: I assume there is some more code involved, as it simply can't be true. Same code under same environment should produce same results. Or you're running it under different iOS versions (maybe even devices) so it uses different fonts. Last assumption is not likely to be true.

Comment: Running it under same simulator. That is my question precisely. There has to be some more code involved which is not seen explicitly. I mean, as we see it, these four lines of code seem like independent.